# Изменение исходников в gcc

Tags: c++, gcc, g++, openmp

У меня есть задание разобрать работу библиотеки `omp.h`. Я работаю с исходниками `gcc`. В качестве теста я хотел изменить функцию `omp_get_thread_num()` таким образом, чтобы она всегда возвращала константу (256 в моем случае). Изменив функцию в файле `parallel.c`, я сделал `make` и `make install` для исходников `gcc` и запустил тестовую программу. Однако функция `omp_get_thread_num()` по-прежнему выдает результат, отличный от 256. В чем моя ошибка?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я не знаю, в чем именно состоит ошибка, но пишу по-существу что именно мне помогло: после замен операционных систем `OpenSuse 11.3` и `OpenSuse 12.3`, на которых я пытался работать на `Ubuntu 12.04` всё заработало. То есть я успешно вносил изменения в исходники gcc и они вступали в силу. Если кому нужно: я пользовался [этой инструкцией](https://solarianprogrammer.com/2012/04/13/building-gcc-4-7-on-ubuntu-12-04/) по построению и установке компилятора.